# Deleting all nodes smaller than x in singly linked list in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I making a program that the lets the user enter countless integers until the number 0 is entered, then display and sort it from smallest to largest. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
} node;

node * insert(node *head, int num)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = num;

    if (head == NULL || head->data > num)
    {
        temp->ptr = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *current = head;
        while ((current->ptr != NULL) && !(num < current->ptr->data))

        {
            current = current->ptr;
        }

        temp->ptr = current->ptr;
        current->ptr = temp;
    }

    return head;
}

void free_list(node *head) {
    node *prev = head;
    node *cur = head;
    while(cur) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = prev->ptr;
        free(prev);
    }
}

int main(){
    int num, min;
    node *head, *p;
    head = NULL;

    do {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if(num) {
            head = insert(head, num);
            for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->ptr )
            {
                printf("%d->", p->data);
            }
            puts( "NULL " );
        }
    } while(num);

    p = head;
    printf("\nThe entered numbers are:\n");

    while(p) {
        printf("%d->", p->data);
        p = p->ptr;
    }
    free_list(head);
    printf("NULL\n");

    printf("\nEnter minimum: ");
    scanf("%d", & min);

    return 0;
}
```

I however need then to delete all the numbers that are smaller than a specified node, i.e. minimum. Then display the list after the deletion, and how many nodes were deleted.

Finally the average/arithmetic mean of the old list before deletion, and the new list after the deletion to be calculated and displayed.

All in all, the output should look like something like this:

```
Enter number: 5
5->NULL
Enter number: 6
5->6->NULL
Enter number: 3
3->5->6->NULL
Enter number: 9
3->5->6->9->NULL
Enter number: 4
3->4->5->6->9->NULL
Enter number: 0

Entered numbers :
3->4->5->6->9->NULL

Enter minimum: 6
3->4->5->6->9->NULL
4->5->6->9->NULL
5->6->9->NULL
6->9->NULL

Deleted nodes: 3

Old average: 5.4
New average: 7.5
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is your *actual* output? Have you tried to *debug* your code? Like for example use a debugger to step through it statement by statement while monitoring variable and their values *and* drawing all operations using pencil and paper (using labeled boxes for the nodes and arrows for the pointers or links, erasing and redrawing the arrows as you perform operations).

Comment: Oh, you haven't actually *tried* anything yet? Then please use pencil and paper to attempt and solve the problem *first*, before writing any code. Once you get it to work on paper then translate the operations into code. And if you have problems, then debug your code.

Comment: Which part of the problem do you need help? Based in your code, it doesn't seem you tried to solve all of it

Comment: Your code looks fine so far. But anyway, don't try to do anything with the list once you have called `free_list`.

Comment: Hint: the write a function like `head = delete_smaller(head, 3)` which will delete all nodes smaller than 3. The function should be no longer than 5-6 lines. Get inspired by the `free_list` function which is pretty similar.

Comment: @taha-hagar try to write `delete_small_nodes()` yourself. Make `display_list()` a separate function.

Comment: Hint 2: the `average` function is really simple, you should be able to write it in a matter of minutes, it's does almost the same thing as your `while(p)` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account this output

```
Enter minimum: 6
3->4->5->6->9->NULL
4->5->6->9->NULL
5->6->9->NULL
6->9->NULL
```

it seems that the function that removes a node from the list should remove at most one node in each its call.

If so then the function can look for example the following way

```
int delete_if_less( node **head, int data )
{
    while ( *head != NULL && !( ( *head )->data < data ) )
    {
        head = &( *head )->ptr;
    }

    int success = *head != NULL

    if ( success )
    {
        node *temp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->ptr;
        free( temp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called in a loop provided that the variable `num` contains the target value for example the following way

```
size_t n = 0;
do
{            
    for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->ptr )
    {
        printf("%d->", p->data);
    }
    puts( "NULL" );
} while ( delete_if_less( &head, num ) && ++n );
```

After this do-while loop the variable n will contain the number of removed nodes in the list.

If you want to remove all nodes that satisfy the condition then the function can look the following way

```
size_t delete_if_less( node **head, int data )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->data < data )
        {
            node *temp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->ptr;
            free( temp );
            ++n;
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->ptr;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

and the function can be called like

```
size_t n = delete_if_less( &head, num );

if ( n != 0 ) printf( "There are deleted %zu nodes.\n", n );
```

Another way to define the function is the following

```
node * delete_if_less( node *head, int data )
{
    while ( head != NULL && head->data < data )
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->ptr;
        free( temp );
    }

    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        for ( node *current = head; current->ptr != NULL; )
        {  
            if ( current->ptr->data < data )
            {
                node *temp = current->ptr;
                current->ptr = current->ptr->ptr;
                free( temp );
            } 
            else
            {
                current = current->ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

And the function is called like

```
head = delete_if_less( head, num );
```

Comment: Actually it doesnt have have to remove one node each call, thats how I wrote it to show the steps. It is enough if the new list after deletion is displayed. Thank You

Comment: @TahaHagar See my appended post.